# Не работает локальное подключение к MS SQL Server при использовании iptables (ubuntu)

Tags: iptables, localhost

У меня на сервере ubuntu установлен SQL Server и dotnet приложение. Без настроек iptables приложение подключается к SQL.
Нужно было запретить внешнее подключение к SQL всем кроме моего ip (ноутбука).
Но как только сделал эти настройки, dotnet приложение перестало подключаться, хотя со своего ноутбука я могу подключиться к sql.
Настройки iptables:
-A INPUT -s 192.168.22.62/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT # доступ с ноутбука (работает)
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT # по идее для локального dotnet приложения (не работает)
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1433 -j DROP # запрещаем остальным

Строка подключения dotnet приложения: Server=localhost,1433;.........
В чем может быть причина

Answer (score 1):

Решение было в правильной команде. Т.к. не всегда идут запросы по IP 127.0.0.1
Поэтому вместо

```
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
```

Нужно

```
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
```